# The same Enum gets shared accross JUnit tests

Tags: enums, junit4

I have an enum like the following:

```
    public enum MyEnum {

        FIRST(new FirstOperations()),
        SECOND(new SecondOperations())
...
```

My problem is that if I have 2 different Unit Tests classes and both declare `MyEnum my = MyEnum.FIRST;` then the `FirstOperations` class will only get instantiated by first Unit Test that runs. The second Test case will resue it.

Why does JUnit hold on to these enums in the heap? Shouldn't they be garbage collected once the first Test case completes?

Comment: By the way I'm using JUnit 4.11 and Java 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerations are perfect examples of Singeltons (e.g. see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternSingleton/article.html)). That's why they only get instantiated once - unless you fork the JVM on each test.

Do not rely on the Garbage Collector. You never know when it runs.